# How to make a new date format with abbreviated names of months with the datetime package?

Tags: datetime

I am looking to save and re-use dates which needs to be displayed in a format such as `Oct. 25`.

How do I do that please?

I read the documentation in `datetime` package. They do have `shortmonthname` which would display months by the abbreviation. They also allows storing and displaying stored dates. But I don't know how to combine the two.

Comment: `datetime` is 'obsolete',perhaps `datetime2` is the better alternative

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `datetime2` has the advantage of being maintained. `datetime` has the advantage of working. ;)

Comment: @cfr: As I have shown in the answer (if that was requested at all)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Indeed. But why? Usually, you wouldn't write an answer using an obsolete package. If somebody asked for `subfigure` say, or `times`, you'd write an answer explaining how to use `subcaption` or `subfig`, perhaps, or one of the current Times-alike support packages. I'm just curious: if `datetime2` is better, why not provide an answer with that? (I know why I wouldn't. I'm just curious why somebody would more-or-less say not to use `datetime` and then demonstrate how to use it.) [But ignore me: I'm irritated about `datetime(2)` and it is not your fault ;).]

Comment: @cfr: Because I've not used `datetime2` so far and no time to read the manual ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Ah. That explains it. I've ***tried*** to use `datetime2` and am sticking with `datetime`. Or, at least, with my bug-fixed version of `datetime`. (The bug fix is for a translation. The language pack for `datetime2` is unmaintained. That for `datetime` is obsolete. I cannot fix the bug for `datetime2`. I can fix it for `datetime`. But a fix for `datetime` will not be accepted - only one for `datetime2`. Hence, the only available packages for doing this available via CTAN use bits of Breton if you use Welsh. Even though a perfectly serviceable fix for `datetime` is ready.)

Comment: @cfr: You should ask Nicola about that all ;-) I've not considered to bully her with my Alemannic language support so far (yet! ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Well, it is not really her problem. The language packs are independent.

Comment: @cfr: Ah, I thought Nicola would provide the language 'packs' as well. Thanks for information

Comment: @ChristianHupfer There are stubs provided but most of the packs have Nicola listed as 'inactive'. I think the idea is that other people (who know the language) should adopt these. In some cases, this seems to have happened and there is an active maintainer, but most are unmaintained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `datetime` dates can be stored to a symbolic name, say 'mydate' with `\newsavedate{mydate}{daynumber}{monthnumber}{yearnumber}`

`\displaydate{mydate}` will display this date using the current date format, whereas `\getdatemonth{mydate}` will extract the month of the saved date.

Using `\shortmonthname[\getdatemonth{mydate}]` it's possible to show the 3-letter abbreviation of the month (see the example)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datetime}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\newdate{mydate}{23}{10}{2015}

\begin{document}
Not today: \displaydate{mydate}

The month of \displaydate{mydate} is \textcolor{red}{\shortmonthname[\getdatemonth{mydate}]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

Using a `\newdateformat` any call to `\mydateformat` will show this format, that's why a 'wrapper macro' (or grouping) is appropiate:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datetime}

\newdateformat{mydateformat}{\shortmonthname[\THEMONTH]. \THEDAY}
\newcommand{\myshortformat}[1]{%
{% group here!
  \mydateformat%
  \displaydate{#1}%
}%
}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\newdate{mydate}{23}{10}{2015}

\begin{document}
Not today: \displaydate{mydate}

The month of \displaydate{mydate} is \textcolor{red}{\shortmonthname[\getdatemonth{mydate}]}

The saved date was in (short format): \myshortformat{mydate}

Today is: \today

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But how do you display `Oct 25` from `mydate`? Are you suggesting making a new macro?

Comment: @Argyll: I'll post an update in a few minutes

Comment: @Argyll: See the update